# Alphabetically listing a dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql

I want order my activityComboHtml alphabetically. Any help would be appreciated.

```
static function GetInnerContent()
{
    $activityComboHtml=Page::getActivityTitles();
    $ageComboHtml=Page::getAgeComboHtml();
    $displayBanner="";
    $bannerUrl=Page::fetchAllOrganizaitonBanners();
    $staticBanner=  HelpingDBMethods::getStaticBanner();
    if($bannerUrl=="-1")
    {
        $displayBanner="style='display:none'";

    }
    return
```

Here is the static function

```
 static function getActivityTitles(){
    $html="";
    $Query="Select uniqueId, name from tbl_activity_type_general where NOT(uniqueId = '12')";
    $result=  mysql_query($Query);
    if($result)
    {
        while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
             $html=$html."<option id='".$row['uniqueId']."' value='".$row['uniqueId']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }
    }
```

Comment: Could you do a `print_r()` on $activityComboHtml ? Can't tell if this is a string, object, or array.

Comment: Do you have the code for `Page::getActivityTitles()`?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `ORDER BY name` on the end of the SQL in `getActivityTitles()`?

Comment: where do you suggest I add it?

Comment: on the end of the SQL in getActivityTitles()

Comment: I keep trying that and the only thing I can think is I am placing it in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL query to

```
SELECT `uniqueId`, `name`
FROM `tbl_activity_type_general`
WHERE NOT( `uniqueId` = '12' )
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

So, the statement becomes:

```
$Query="SELECT `uniqueId`, `name` FROM `tbl_activity_type_general` WHERE NOT( `uniqueId` = '12' ) ORDER BY `name` ASC";
```

Comment: That is where I placed it, however it keeps dumping the values. Thanks very much for the response.

Comment: @MarcMcEwan Please define: `keeps dumping the values`.

Comment: I wish, I could say it was some profound fix, however I forgot where to place my qoutes.... sorry for looking stupid...

Comment: @MarcMcEwan One more note, if `uniqueID` is of INT type, you don't need to compare 12 using `'12'`. Just a simple `uniqueId = 12` would do better job.